# C# using filewatcher to monitor folder to send an email when pdf is received with attachment of pdf

Tags: c#, email, pdf, attachment

I have the following code to watch a folder for incoming files. Once the folder receives the files, the program sends an email along with an attachment of the file, in this case, a pdf.
However, sometimes we receive more than one file and it sends multiple emails with the same pdf, but with a different file name. Do I have to release the pdf files? I thought I was doing that with the pdfFile.Dispose() and mail.Dispose().

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Email
{
class Program
{
    static string files;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        fileWatcher();
    }

    private static void fileWatcher()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a filesystemwatcher to monitor the path for documents.
            string path = @"\\server\folder\";
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);

            //Watch for changes in the Last Access, Last Write times, renaming of files and directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;

            watcher.Filter = "FILE*";

            //Register a handler that gets called when a file is created.
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Created);

            //Register a handler that gets called if the FileSystemWatcher need to report an error.
            watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(watcher_Error);

            //Begin watching the path for budget documents/
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Monitoring incoming files for Budget documents.");
            Console.WriteLine("Please do not close.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit the program.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught", e);
        }
    }


    //This method is called when a file is created.
    static void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            //Show that a file has been created
            WatcherChangeTypes changeTypes = e.ChangeType;
            Console.WriteLine("File {0} {1}", e.FullPath, changeTypes.ToString());
            String fileName = e.Name.ToString();
            sendMail(fileName);


            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught", exc);
        }
    }

    static void watcher_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file watcher has detected an error.");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static void sendMail(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("From@mail.com");
            mail.To.Add("Me@mail.com");

            string filesDirectory = @"\server\folder\";
            string searchForFile = "FILE*";
            string[] searchFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filesDirectory, searchForFile);

            foreach (string File in searchFiles)
                files = File;
            Attachment pdfFile = new Attachment(files);

            mail.Subject = "PDF Files " + fileName;
            mail.Body = "Attached is the pdf file " + fileName + ".";
            mail.Attachments.Add(pdfFile);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("SMTP.MAIL.COM");

             client.Send(mail);
           //To release files and enable accessing them after they are sent.
            pdfFile.Dispose();
            mail.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught", e);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is designed to find the last pdf in the directory and send that as the attachment with the newly created PDF filename as the file name in the email.

This is due to this code here.

```
string[] searchFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filesDirectory, searchForFile);

foreach (string File in searchFiles)
      files = File;
Attachment pdfFile = new Attachment(files);

mail.Subject = "PDF Files " + fileName;
```

If you look closely you will notice in your foreach loop it is looping all files that match your filter in the directory then setting the variable files to the file in the loop. Once the loop is finished your files variable will be the last file in the directory.

Next you are attaching the last file to the email and setting the subject to the filename passed in as a parameter.

You would be better off locating the file exists then adding the file as an attachment such as.

```
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
    mail.From = new MailAddress("From@mail.com");
    mail.To.Add("Me@mail.com");

    //format our file paths
    string filesDirectory = @"\server\folder\";
    string fileFullPath = Path.Combine(filesDirectory, fileName);

    //file doesnt exist so exit the method
    if (!File.Exists(fileFullPath))
        return;

    using (var pdfFile = new Attachment(fileFullPath))
    {
        mail.Subject = "PDF Files " + fileName;
        mail.Body = "Attached is the pdf file " + fileName + ".";
        mail.Attachments.Add(pdfFile);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("SMTP.MAIL.COM");

        client.Send(mail);
        //To release files and enable accessing them after they are sent.
    }
}
```

In the example above (yes i switched to using statements) but you will notice i am no longer searching the entire directory but only checking if the file that was created still exists. Instead of looping all files this will only transmit the newly created file.

Let me know how it goes.

Cheers

Comment: Your changes worked exactly as I needed it to. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.